# How to share an iTunes library with other user accounts on the same machine?

Tags: itunes, music, user-account

I would like to share the iTunes library my the account of my wife.

But (in importance order):

- files should not be duplicated
- playlist and rating are user dependent
- podcast are user dependent

Then, she will managed her ipod with her account.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was going to start explaining you what you can (and can’t) do or how hard was this going to be, but a single google query lead me to this [excellent thread](http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=9505120) an Apple forum.

I’m going to quote the relevant part, but I suggest you read it all because there’s more information there and more “why” questions.

We assume you have copied all the music to a Central location (be it a machine or a NAS drive or whatever), so somewhere in the network or your harddrive all your music files (library) are accessible to your wife and you (and theoretically both can write to that location, important when adding files).

It doesn’t matter if they are in different computers or just accounts.

With that in mind:

1. Each future user of the library should launch iTunes with the Option key held down and Create Library. (A blank one).
2. With this new iTunes window open, go into iTunes Preferences and **UN-check "Keep iTunes Music folder organised" and "Copy files to iTunes Music folder when adding to library".**
3. Then, they must add the music to the Library, selecting the tracks from the folder where all the music is stored (the common place mentioned above), which will import all the tracks into this new Library without copying the files again (hence why step #2).
4. From this point they can create their own playlists and stuff and they can even *check* the things they unchecked in step #2, in case they decide to add new tracks (see drawback), you’ll want to have them in the central location.

From this point they both have a Library.XML (stores playlists, tracks location, etc.) and that library.xml points to the physical mp3/4 on the “common location” (tracks are not duplicated as you requested).

**DRAWBACK** (and the fact that there’s no better solution):

If either user of the library adds new music, regardless of the “keep music organized” and “copy files” checkboxes, the other user(s) are **not** going to see the changes. The reason being that they are modifying their local copy of the library “xml” (which is where all the playlist and stuff is stored).

If USER1 adds 1 track, USER2 will have to find the track in the library and manually add it to his/her own library.

As you can see, iTunes was not really designed for multiuser.

Go ahead and read the post, it will give you more pros/cons and maybe other ideas.

**EDIT**: one way to know “what is new” in the library folder (where the music is actually stored) would be to create a smart folder that shows files added in the last “xx” days (for example). :)

Comment: Thx for your answer and the link...

Comment: +1 on this route. There really isn't a way to do this, and I recently went through this at home. My wife and I keep separate libraries, but do share stuff now through home sharing (where you can copy b/t libraries). You may be able to write some AppleScripts though to update both libraries when something new is added to the file server.

Comment: This is exactly how we do it at my house, and it doesn't suck. And hey, that drawback can become a neat surprise when you find out what new stuff is on the network drive to add to your library!

Comment: @Ben you’re welcome. @jmlump and @Dan hehe yes, there’s really no other way to do it. Those of us who happen to live in Europe, use Spotify for most of our music needs :)

Comment: In France we have also Deezer, but I already have a subtential iTunes library... Thank all for your answers

Comment: @Ben yes, me too, around 80 gb :) but I stopped adding stuff to it… except when I want something on the iPhone, in fact, I removed lots of stuff :)

Comment: @Martin: I have all my CDs on iTunes, but maybe it's time to go on cloud.

Comment: @Ben I ripped all my rather large (back then) collection of more than 200CDs to iTunes. Probably 7 years ago. I used it a lot. But moving 80gb of information here and there has been an annoyance (backups… awful). So i slowly started to trust the cloud and leave only rare things or things I really like (or brought, I have a lot of iTunes tracks brought). There’s no reason to carry 80gb of music around anymore for me :)

Comment: "Then, they must add the music to the Library, selecting the tracks from the folder where all the music is stored" does this mean each file has to be manually imported into the new user's playlists? I have hundreds of playlists and this would be too combersome

Answer (score 3):

There's an app called [PowerTunes](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/powertunes/) that will keep all of the meta-data for a library synchronized between multiple users on a machine. Playlists, ratings, play counts -- all of that stuff that isn't just the physical files. It'll obviously keep all of the iTunes instances for all users aware of all the current physical files on disk too.

Comment: I don't want to synchronize meta-data. They could be different for each users

Answer (score 0):

You should make `~/Music/iTunes/` a symlink to a shared location accessible to all users of the computer.

Comment: Has anyone actually tried this and does it work?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to sign in to iTunes match on both accounts. They will then keep in sync. You will have the same playlists on both though.